# Unable to load csv by read_csv("")

Tags: r

I was able to load a dataset by using `read.csv()`, but unable to load the exact same dataset using `read_csv()`, followed by the message down below in the console.

> Error in file(con, "rb") : cannot open the connection In addition:
> Warning message: In file(con, "rb") :   cannot open file
> 'C:/Users/inomi/OneDrive/??????/L2_Upload/program_data.csv': Invalid
> argument

The code I used are

```
dpss <- read.csv("program_data.csv") 
dpss <- read_csv("program_data.csv")
```

It would be great if anyone could help me on this, since I would like to use the data by `read_csv`. As a matter of fact, my working directory has been correctly set.

Comment: Please provide codes used for read.csv and read_csv. Which package is read_csv from?

Comment: The reason that `read_csv` is not working could be due to your code or the data in the file. In addition to zx8754's request for code, please provide enough sample data (raw contents of the CSV file itself, in a code block please) that can trigger the problem. (For instance, try the first 10 rows; if it doesn't trigger, add more rows until you trigger the problem.)

Comment: OneDrive does not always play well with R. Try using a folder on your local machine rather than a OneDrive folder.